# How to combine 2 mysql queries to 1 table into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have one table, example

```
catid | parentcatid | dirname
  4   |      0      | mobiles 
 243  |      4      | Nokia
```

When I get `catid = 243` I need to take with `mysql_query (catid=parentcatid)`

```
243 | mobiles | Nokia
```

I can first select `catid`, `parentcatid`, and `dirname` where `id=243` and then select the same where `parentcatid = catid`, but

**How to make this single query ?**

Comment: I know about joins, not many, so dont want to waste an hour to make 1 query that I need, so asked you, guys, to help me faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JOIN` the table twice:

```
SELECT
  t2.catid, t1.dirname 'dirname', t2.dirname 'parentname'
FROM Tablename t1
INNER JOIN Tablename t2 ON t1.catid = t2.parentcatid
WHERE t2.catid = 243;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55658/4)

This will give you:

```
| CATID | DIRNAME | PARENTNAME |
--------------------------------
|   243 | mobiles |      Nokia |
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT parent.catid, parent.dirname
FROM yourtable AS parent
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS child ON (child.parentcatid = parent.catid)
WHERE child.catid = 243
```

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is to use a self-join (as Marc B suggests).

Reading between the lines, I'm assuming that you don't know how deep your hierarchy is going to be in advance - that makes the self join less useful, because if you have to continue to join to get deeper levels of the tree, and you probably need to user outer joins if not all parts of the tree go to the same depth.

The alternative approaches - much more complex, and only do this if my assumption is true - is to [use a recursive function](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/), or to represent your data as a [nested set](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html).

Comment: Thanks for the articles, my tree has only 2 levels :)